# Jquery .not() change image src - data-other-src

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to change img src with Jquery to data-other-src.  Can we not implement with .not()?

Jquery:

```
 $('.listItem').not(this).attr({src:$(this).attr("data-other-src")});
```

HTML (there are numerous links):

```
 <a href="#" class="listItem"><img src="../img/updown.png" class="previewImg" data-other-src="../img/here.png"/></a>
```

Comment: what is `this` in this context?

Comment: this pertains to a listItem from a click event

Comment: Please include all of your code then. and why are you targeting `.listItem` (an `a`) to set a `src` attribute. do you mean to target `.listItem img` instead?

Comment: `data-other-src` is also an attribute of the `img`, not `.listItem`.

Comment: OMGosh!  Yeah you are right.  Yes, list item is the a tag not the img tag.  That makes total sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src` and `data-other-src` attributes are on the `img`, not `.listItem`, so you need to use `.child()` to access the `img`.

```
$('.listItem').not(this).children("img").attr('src', $(this).children("img").data("other-src"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, sending proper jQuery Object in `not()`

```
$('.listItem').not($(this)).attr( 'src' ,$(this).attr("data-other-src"));
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not/) says that the argument can be either a jQuery object or a DOM element. So `this` should work just as well as `$(this)`.

Comment: You are right, I always used jQuery object though. Thanks